# Slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04 LTs

Tags: boot, 18.04

For a week i've been experiencing a very slow boot on my system.
Here is a result of systemd-analyze blame:

```
50.961s vmware-workstation-server.service
     26.680s dev-sda1.device
     24.653s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     23.519s systemd-journal-flush.service
     23.178s keyboard-setup.service
     18.941s mysql.service
     16.426s lvm2-monitor.service
     15.701s systemd-udevd.service
     14.480s systemd-sysctl.service
      6.972s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.991s plymouth-start.service
      5.951s NetworkManager.service
      5.512s snapd.service
      5.116s tor@default.service
      4.912s udisks2.service
      4.358s ModemManager.service
      4.212s networkd-dispatcher.service
      4.134s accounts-daemon.service
      3.831s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
      3.705s libvirtd.service
      3.647s thermald.service
      3.534s virtualbox.service
      3.242s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
```

And systemd-analyze critical-chain:

```
graphical.target @1min 39.914s
└─multi-user.target @1min 39.914s
  └─vmware-workstation-server.service @48.953s +50.961s
    └─network-online.target @45.787s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @38.814s +6.972s
        └─NetworkManager.service @32.861s +5.951s
          └─dbus.service @32.821s
            └─basic.target @32.821s
              └─sockets.target @32.821s
                └─snapd.socket @32.798s +22ms
                  └─sysinit.target @32.774s
                    └─cryptsetup.target @32.774s
                      └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @3.501s
                        └─-.mount @3.487s
                          └─system.slice @3.501s
                            └─-.slice @3.487s
```

I know it's a lot. I can see may be what's the problem. But I don't have any idea how to solve it. Would appreciate your help.

**update**

```
23.122s dev-sda1.device
     17.428s keyboard-setup.service
     17.241s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     15.802s lvm2-monitor.service
     15.701s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
     14.746s systemd-journal-flush.service
     14.029s systemd-sysctl.service
     12.552s mysql.service
      7.669s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.739s snapd.service
      6.179s tor@default.service
      6.151s plymouth-start.service
      4.449s NetworkManager.service
      4.443s libvirtd.service
      4.414s networkd-dispatcher.service
      4.078s udisks2.service
      2.674s systemd-udevd.service
      2.214s thermald.service
      2.175s ModemManager.service
      2.083s accounts-daemon.service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry for dev-sda1.device and a couple of the other entries indicates the problem is the speed of your hard disk drive.

An SSD (solid-state drive) would significantly speed up boot.

Note that slowness in services like plymouth-quit-wait.service simply indicate that it's waiting for something else - in this case, flushes to disk.

If you are noticing it getting worse, it may be that your hard drive is filling up or you've installed more software, which can make boot a little slower, though replacing the hard drive would make the most improvement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand that, still i have a laptop, which is only 1 y.o. And i'd like to speed up booting without replacing. By this time, i've speeded it up from 120-130sec to 70-80sec.    Can you tell me which of these problems i can solve with out replacing. I've updated a question