# Xubuntu 18.04 very slow boot on an NVMe SSD

Tags: boot, xubuntu, nvme

My Xubuntu 18.04 system experiences a very slow boot - looks like the kernel hangs for approximately 90 seconds during the boot (before handing off control to systemd).
For comparison, Windows 10 as a secondary system boots up in 10-15 seconds. This is what I would expect from a workstation running dual Xeon Silver 4110 and booting off of a NVMe SSD - not an over 2 minute boot time.

I tried analyzing the times as the OP in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1088124/599356), here is the output of `systemd-analyze`:
`Startup finished in 1min 34.506s (kernel) + 39.871s (userspace) = 2min 14.377s`
`graphical.target reached after 11.494s in userspace`
What the heck is the kernel doing for so long?

`systemd-analyze blame` says this (these are only the first 5 entries - all others combined take less than 10 seconds, for a grand total of about 48 seconds):

```
     15.608s apt-daily.service
     14.775s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      6.261s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      2.021s postfix@-.service
      1.155s zfs-fuse.service
```

I checked `dmesg` as well, seeking for any gaps as [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/39517/599356). There's a lot of stuff going on for the first 3 seconds, and then...

```
[    3.177248] sr 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[    3.180142] random: fast init done
[    3.180463] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.180494] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.180505] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   94.416745] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   94.538084] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   94.558536] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
```

91 seconds spent on what exactly? I tried to check what does the `EXT4-fs` line mean and found [this bug in Fedora 18](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=953414), which gave the suggestion to check mounts. Here's the relevant line from `mount` output:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

**What is going on here?** As I suppose it might be relevant, here's my partition layout (`blkid`):

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="92606867" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="e202280b-c8bb-4420-96d5-7b61ef8d9cca" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="92606867-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="ZastrzeM-EM-<one przez system" UUID="04B86A80B86A6FDA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="92606867-03"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="F4766BFA766BBBCC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="92606867-04"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="875adb3f-9abd-43f7-a909-aa8a77676004" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="92606867-05"
/dev/sda: LABEL="tank" UUID="9630541256789858078" UUID_SUB="7514627587335991623" TYPE="zfs_member"
/dev/sdb: LABEL="tank" UUID="9630541256789858078" UUID_SUB="7746526721653217213" TYPE="zfs_member"
/dev/sdc: LABEL="tank" UUID="9630541256789858078" UUID_SUB="15647716461375923660" TYPE="zfs_member"
```

There's an NVMe SSD drive that I boot from, it has a "msdos" partition table (as reported by gparted), partitioned as follows:

- p1: linux-swap
- p2: extended partition containing p5, which contains the Xubuntu system
- p3: windows 10 boot partition (language is Polish, hence the weird name)
- p4: windows 10 system

There are also 3 HDDs in a ZFS matrix but they shouldn't matter. No idea what all those loops are.

---

As per Simon's request, here's the output of `cat /proc/cmdline`:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-20-generic root=UUID=875adb3f-9abd-43f7-a909-aa8a77676004 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
```

---

Update: I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1049693/599356) but neither the `rng-tools` answer nor the `RESUME` one improved the situation. I also tried to set the resume volume UUID directly as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1122636/599356) but to no avail.

Comment: Can you add the output from `cat /proc/cmdline` to your post?

Comment: @SimonSudler Done.

Comment: strange.... but I don't think the delay is comming from the NVM. Do you have a additional network device, that is maybe waiting for a DHCP replay?

Comment: I do mount some Samba shares but they do not influence the boot time - verified by removing related `fstab` entries and rebooting - `dmesg` still shows approximately 90 second gap. However, now it happened before the `random:` lines.

Comment: have you tried booting into the rescue system? Do you see the 90 seconds there as well?

Comment: I did. It does hang as well. My colleague suggests that it might be running `fsck` on the NVMe partition - do you have any idea on how could I verify that it's the case *or* disable that check? AFAIK it should be routinely conducted every *n* boots, but not everytime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94349/discussion-between-przemek-d-and-simon-sudler).

Comment: Edit grub cmdline by adding `fastboot` after `quiet splash`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks, but this changed nothing - I observe the same 90 second gap in `dmesg`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)